# Mapping separate fields into one string using Automapper

Tags: c#, string, field, concatenation, automapper

I have spent a couple of days trying to track this down without any luck.

I have a table of addresses.  Each row has 4 address fields. I want to map them to another object that has one field that is a single string made up of the 4 fields, but (there's always a but), if one of the fields contains a null or an empty string I want to ignore it.

e.g.
The address table contains :-
                            Address1 = House Number
                            Address2 = Street
                            Address3 = 
                            Address4 = Town

New object would contain the string :-
                            House Number, Street, Town.

As requested this is where I am at :-

The AutoMapper config file

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new AddressSearchList_ToResponse_Profile());
        });
    }
}
```

The Profile Definition :

```
    public class AddressSearchList_ToResponse_Profile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressSearchResponseDto>()
            .ConvertUsing<ConvertAddressToSearchList>();

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        //This is as far as I get - what am I missing

    }
}
```

And finally the conversion routine (admittedly not the slickest code ever):

```
public class ConvertAddressToSearchList : ITypeConverter<Address, AddressSearchResponseDto>
{

    public AddressSearchResponseDto Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {

        string newAddress = string.Empty;
        Address oldAddress = (Address)context.SourceValue;
        int addressId = oldAddress.Id;

        newAddress = oldAddress.AddressLine1;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldAddress.AddressLine2))
        {
            newAddress += ", " + oldAddress.AddressLine2;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldAddress.AddressLine3))
        {
            newAddress += ", " + oldAddress.AddressLine3;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldAddress.AddressLine4))
        {
            newAddress += ", " + oldAddress.AddressLine4;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldAddress.County))
        {
            newAddress += ", " + oldAddress.County;
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oldAddress.Postcode))
        {
            newAddress += ".  " + oldAddress.Postcode;
        }


        AddressSearchResponseDto searchAddress = new AddressSearchResponseDto { Id = addressId, Address = newAddress };

        return searchAddress;

    }
```

Thanks

Steve

Comment: any code sample please

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I've updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this change the Profile Definition to :

```
public class AddressSearchList_ToResponse_Profile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressSearchResponseDto>()
            .ConvertUsing<ConvertAddressToSearchList>();

    }
}
```

Then in the code that calls the automapper gubbins you need to do this :

```
var query = from a in addressRepository.GetAll() select a;

IList<AddressSearchResponseDto> result = Mapper.Map<IList<Address>, IList<AddressSearchResponseDto>>(query.ToList());
```

result now holds the correct data.

Thanks you very much for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it's just me, but (there's always a but), what is the question?

I think it's already converted, you just missing the code to actually mapping the source entity and display the result to monitor, like this:

```
AddressSearchResponseDto result = Mapper.Map<Address,AddressSearchResponseDto>(source); 
Console.WriteLine(result.newAddress);
```

Comment: How do I take the four separate fields from object 1 and using automapper turn them into one field ignoring any that are null or empty>

Comment: But, you were already using one. Your code is not error, right?

Comment: The code doesnt error - it just returns an empty address.  I know it has something to do with this ITypeConverter.  I cant figure out how to get it to fire and give me back the data I want

Comment: I think it's already converted, you just missing the code to see the result like this:
    AddressSearchResponseDto result = Mapper.Map<Address,AddressSearchResponseDto>(source);
    Console.WriteLine(result.newAddress);

Comment: Thank you - you pushed me in the right direction.  Answer coming in the next post :)